# Using react-native-datepicker in mode="datetime" mode how I can hide time?

Tags: ios, react-native, datepicker

I want to hide time in react-native-datepicker, when I use mode as "datetime". I just want to show date with day like "Mon 13 Jul 2020". Any workaround will be helpful.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use mode "date", if you need to set time, you could add a new `DatePicker` mode "time"?

Comment: @高鵬翔 I'm looking for is just the day of the week and the date, like "Mon 13 Jul 2020".

Comment: It looks have these information at gif using "date" when it choosing the time, at the message box. Oh but it may be android form?

Comment: The only way I think you could try is using props format to other style may work? Or I have no idea, sorry..